# Transfer steam without games

Tags: steam

I want to transfer the steam app from my pc to HD, then to another pc. is it possible since my profile is saved to it?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just install the fresh program on the second computer? As far as I know, steam needs to log in at least once to create a local profile.

Comment: dont have internet at the moment

Comment: And are you physically moving the hard drive to use as a boot drive for pc #2?

Comment: its an external hard drive

Comment: It shouldn't work then. The only way it might work is if you manually put in each required registry entry on the second machine.

Comment: Even if this worked, you'd almost certainly have difficulty playing the games with no internet if Steam doesn't get to check in at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem: when you're installing any program, it automatically has to make several changes to your registry. This is the same with Steam. Among these are an InstallPath, a Language, a SteamPID and others. The InstallPath and Language could in theory be entered manually. However, the SteamPID is a unique key that's different from computer to computer. I have 3 machines with Steam installed on them, and all 3 of them has a different SPID. I even think that, were I to reinstall Steam on one of them (which I'm currently doing), I'd get a different PID.

In addition, when you start Steam on a new machine for the first time, you need to connect to the Steam servers to log in. You literally CANNOT log in or start a game on your computer without first authenticating with the live servers.